# How to mock Spring 5 WebClient in spring boot API testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, mocking, integration-testing, spring-webclient

I have a spring boot API which internally calls two 3rd party API's using Spring WebClient. I need to test my API end to end by mocking the two API calls. How can I create a MockWebServer to mock the two API calls in my DAOImpl class.

I tried configuring a MockWebServer to mock the WebClient, but its not working.

## My Controller

```java
@Autowired
private DemoDao dao;

@RequestMapping(value = "/webClient/testing", produces = { "application/json"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> webClientNonBlockingClient(@RequestHeader(value = "name_id", required = false) String nameId)
  {
    HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.OK;
    String userId = dao.getUserId(nameId);
    boolean userCheck = dao.checkUserAccess(nameId, userId);
    if (userCheck)
    {
      message = "check success";
    }
    else
    {
      message = "check failed";
      httpStatus = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED;
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(message, httpStatus);
  }
```

## DAO impl class

```java
@Repository
public class DemoDAOImpl
{

  @Autowired
  private WebClientFactory webClientFactory;

  public String getUserId(String nameId)
  {
    UserProfile profile = new UserProfile();
    Mono<UserProfile> response = null;
    try
    {
      String url = "/user/"+nameId+"/profile"
      WebClient client = webClientFactory.getWebClient();
      response = client.get().uri(builder -> 
      builder.path(url).build()).retrieve().bodyToMono(UserProfile.class);
      profile = response.block();
    }
    catch (WebClientResponseException e)
    {
      LOG.error("ResponseException {}", e);
    }
    return profile.getUserId();
  }
  
  public boolean userCheck(String nameId, String userId)
  {
    Mono<UserAccessResponse> result = null;
    try
    {
      WebClient client = webClientFactory.getWebClient();
      String url = "/user/"+nameId+"/check"
      result = client.get().uri(builder -> builder.path(url).queryParam("userId", userId).build())
          .retrieve().bodyToMono(UserAccessResponse.class);
      return result.block().isStatus();
    }
    catch (WebClientResponseException e)
    {
      LOG.error("APIexception {}", e);
    }
  }
```

## webClient configuration class

```java
@Configuration
public class WebClientFactory
{
  
  private String baseUrl = "https://abcd.com/v1/";
  
  private String apikey = "123456";
  
  public WebClientFactory()
  {
    // Default constructor
  }

  @Bean
  @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
  public WebClient getWebClient()
  {
    return WebClient
        .builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, 
 MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .defaultHeader("apikey", apikey)
      .build();
  }  
}
}
```

I tried mocking with below test class, but its not working as expected. i am unable to configure how to mock the 2 external api calls.

## Test class

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration()
@TestPropertySource("classpath:dev-manifest.yml")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class WebClientMockTesting
{

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebClientMockTesting.class);

  private static final String REQUEST_URI = "/webClient/testing";
  private static final String HEADER_KEY = "name_id";
  private static final String MOCK_USER_ID = "mockTest";

  private final MockWebServer mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();

  @Autowired
  private WebClientFactory webClientFactory;

  @Autowired
  private WebClient webClient;

  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

  /**
   * build web application context
   */
  @Before
  public void setup()
  {
    try
    {
      mockWebServer.play(8084);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    webClient = webClientFactory.getWebClient();
    webClient = WebClient.create(mockWebServer.getUrl("/").toString());
    this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
  }

  @AfterEach
  void tearDown() throws IOException
  {
    mockWebServer.shutdown();
  }

  /**
   * Success scenario - GetFutureProjectedIncomeRIC
   */
  @Test
  public void testGetId()
  {
    try
    {
      mockWebServer.enqueue(
          new MockResponse()
                  .setResponseCode(200)
                  .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                  .setBody("{\"y\": \"value for y\", \"z\": 789}")
  );

      mockMvc.perform(get(REQUEST_URI).contentType(contentType).header(HEADER_KEY, MOCK_USER_ID))
          .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      logger.error("test failed due to - {}", e.getStackTrace());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly doesn't work?
In mock web server you create a queue of responses sent back one by one in the order you adding them. In you code you add one response using

```
mockWebServer.enqueue(
```

if you need to do 3 calls from your app you should call enqueue 3 times.

Comment: i am trying to do an end to end API call testing, but need to mock the two API calls that are happening in DAOImpl class. but my Test class setup is not working, i enqueued only one API call and when i debugged the test method its making an actual API call.

Comment: MockWebServer is listening on localhost. You should configure your client to talk to localhost:8084.

Comment: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=com.google.mockwebserver.MockWebServer&method=enqueue